# Python modulo operator giving unexpected result

Tags: python, modulo

I am new to Python and having a problem with the modulo.

Here is the code:

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    print chr(((i+2) % 97) + 97 )
```

The exptected result is `cdef...a`. However I am not getting the desired module behavior of wrapping around once we get to `z`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because 97 isn't what you want to be wrapping at - you want to be wrapping at `ord('z')` = 122, and then adding the value of `ord('a')` (97).

The full math you really need to be doing is to shift into an offset, and then back to the set. For instance...

```
for i in range(ord('z') - ord('a') + 1): # equivalent to range(26); i.e. 0-25
    print chr(((i+2) % 26) + ord('a')) # results in 2+97 'c', 3+97 'd', etc.
```

---

The reason your existing code isn't working is because your `i+2` will always be greater than 97 (since your `i` starts at `ord('a')` which is 97, and goes up from there), so the `% 97` is effectively just `- 97`, and thus your print line is effectively this:

```
print chr(((i+2) - 97) + 97 )
```

which reduces to...

```
print chr((i+2) - 97 + 97)
```

which is obviously just `print chr(i+2)`.

Comment: I did try print chr(((i+2) % 122) + 97 ) and it simply printed out the last three letters a,b and c.

Comment: `(i+2 % 26)` is equivalent to `(i + (2 % 26))`, since [`%` has a higher operator precedence than `+`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary). It should be corrected to `((i + 2) % 26)`. A mnemonic is to remember that `%` is similar to `/`, except in that it gives the reminder of the division. Therefore it has the same precedence as `/`.

Comment: @lazyr - yeah, I'm aware of that, just was retyping the code enough and forgot to add the parens in on the last retype. :) Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

You should work modulo 26 (the number of letters in the English alphabet).  This code will work:

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
   j = i - ord('a')
   print chr(ord('a') + (j + 2) % 26)
```

### Explanation

Consider this indexing template:

```
A + (j + B) % C
```

It will map different values of `j` to the range `A … (A + C - 1)`.  Originally, you have chosen `A = 97` and `C = 97`, so you're mapping to the range `97 … 193`.  I have chosen `A = ord('a') = 97` and `C = 26`, so I'm mapping to the range `97 … 122`, i.e., `ord('a') … ord('z')`.

Now about the offset, `B`.  You wanted to rotate two places to the left, and thus you have correctly chosen `B = 2`.  However, in order to this to work, `a` as the first letter has to be encoded by `0` before the rotation.  Hence `j = i - ord('a')`

Comment: Thanks. The code seems to work. But I'd be thankful if you could provide some clue about the code behaviour in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the value into 0-26 range, modify it, apply the mod, then shift back into the correct character range. Here it is in multiple steps

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    idx = i - ord('a')
    mod_idx = ( idx + 2 ) % 26
    c = chr( mod_idx + ord('a') )
    print( chr(c) )
```

And here's the same thing in oneline (too ugly IMO)

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    print( chr((( i - ord('a')) + 2 ) % 26 + ord('a')) )
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with mod, looping from a number besides 1 can get confusing. Here's your code refactored to use 1 as a starting point.

```
for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
    print chr( (i-97+2) % 26) + 97 ) #Subtract 97, do our modulo and shift, then add 97
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered what is wrong with your code. I'd like to present a solution that doesn't have to deal with the modulo at all. I think this is a cleaner way of doing it because you don't have to deal with the nitty-gritty details of converting back and forth using `ord` and `chr`.

It also works even if you're dealing with foreign alphabets where the character codes are not all in sequence.

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> from collections import deque
>>> chrs = deque(ascii_lowercase)
>>> chrs.rotate(-2)
>>> print "".join(chrs)
cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
```

If you're going to use this for some sort of translation or encoding, just build a dict and off you go:

```
>>> tr = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase, chrs))
>>> "".join(tr.get(x, x) for x in "abcd xyz")
'cdef zab'
```